# Finding memory leaks in jboss with eclipse

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, out-of-memory, jprofiler

**Updated :**
I am using JBoss 6.1.0 Final and Java 1.7.

I am getting Out of Memory Exception frequently after deploying the application.

I increased the Heap Size but it doesn't fix the issue permanently,

I suspect my application may have some memory leakage,

So to fix those issues i tried JProfiler, Eclipse Memory Analyzer, but i didn't understand the process and am unable to fix the leakage.

Does anyone know the perfect tool to fix Memory Leakage issues?

Here is my log :
**Log :**

```
2015-07-03 06:54:00,961 ERROR [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint] (http-8449-Acceptor-0) Socket accept failed: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

2015-07-03 06:55:56,724 ERROR [com.application.us.web.IndexController] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-185) HTTP Status 500 Occurred
2015-07-03 06:56:00,647 ERROR [org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint] (http-8449-Acceptor-0) Socket accept failed: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

2015-07-03 07:00:51,830 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter] (http-127.0.0.1-8080-195) An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the **[Plumbr](https://plumbr.eu/)**.

I was very satisfied with it while hunting memory leaks on JBoss EAP 6.x apps. The free trial period was enough for my testing.

Answer (score 0):

I believe JBOSS 6.x would require JDK 7.x.  I'd recommend upgrading.

Are you running on a 64-bit operating system?  You can't allocate 2GB RAM on a 32-bit OS.

The JVM uses a generational memory model.  I'd recommend looking at the settings for perm gen and others.

2GB should be more than enough.  You're doing something wrong, but you can't tell without some better data.  JMeter isn't the tool for the job.  You need a profiler.  Try Visual VM - it ships with Oracle JVMs.